# Php switch wildcard and test for multiple strings?

Tags: php, menu

I would like to have a wildcard for a specific menu bar below running on a switch statement.

So, I have this PHP code for a dynamic menu bar:

```
    switch($location):
            case "/":
                    echo '
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">' . $name . '</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/parents">Parents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="//staugie.net">Church Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/kids">Kids Area</a></li>';
            break;
            case "/parents/*":
                //I want this to display at any page that is a sub of /parents.
                //Is this the proper syntax?
                break;
    endswitch;
```

so that is my code. I would like the parents one to display when the person is in any sub-folder in the parent's folder. Also, how do I make the case statement test for multiple strings such as:

```
            case "/" || "/home.html":
                //I want this to display at any page that is a sub of /parents.
                //Is this the proper syntax?
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case blocks that do not have jump statements will "fall through". This means you can have multiple statements reach the same block of code:

```
case "/" :
case "/home.html":
    //both case statements fall through to here
    break;
```

Comment: what about the sub folder of parents

Comment: You have to list them individually. There's no way to do wildcards in a switch statement.

Comment: oh. Darn! I wish I could